# How to create a CMD process and send commands to it

Tags: java

In Java I want to create a CMD process and send inputs to it and then output the information that is displayed in the process. Are there any external jars that would allow me to do this?

I have tried using Runtime but I can only run the maximum of one command at a time before the process is closed.

`Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();`

```
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        try
        {  
         // We are running "dir" and "ping" command on cmd 
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"dir && ping localhost\""); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("HEY Buddy ! U r Doing Something Wrong "); 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I need it so the command prompt remains open as I will be running an exe file which outputs different information depending what commands are input.

Comment: Try looking into `JCommander`

Answer (score 1):

You could use ProcessBuilder in a loop and inherit IO.
This should write the output of the process to the same location as the calling process. In this case probably the console.

For more information see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

You could try something like following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> commandArguments = new ArrayList<>();
    while(someCondition){
        commandArguments.add("cmd.exe");
        commandArguments.add("/C");
        commandArguments.add(yourCommands); //Read input from console
        executeCommand(commandArguments)
    }
}

private void executeCommand(List<String> commandArguments){
    if(commandArguments != null){
        try{
            new ProcessBuilder(commandArguments).inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        }catch(IOException, InterruptedException ex){
            ex.printStacktrace();
        }
    }
}
```